# c++ class two dynamic attributes

Tags: c++

In the semplified code below I have a class with two attributes, I need to change one according to the value of the other without changing the value of the second. I don't want to create a new temp variable to do it (I don't want to allocate new memory and clear the old), I need to use pointers

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{

private:

int **m1;
int **m2;

void allocate_mem(int ***ptr){
    *ptr = new int*[1];
    (*ptr)[0] = new int[1];
}

public:

A(){
    allocate_mem(&m1);
    m1[0][0] = 1;
    allocate_mem(&m2);
    m2[0][0] = 1;
}

//I need a method that change m2 (according to the value of m2) without changhig the value of m2
//this following doesn't work
A renew(){
    if(m1[0][0]>0)
        m2[0][0] = 1000;
}

~A(){
    delete[] m1[0];
    delete[] m1;
    delete[] m2[0];
    delete[] m2;    
}

void create_output(){
    cout << m1[0][0] << endl << m2[0][0] << endl;
}

};
```

Comment: Change `m2` without changing `m2`?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?!

Comment: Oh god. That could well be another IOCCC entry. Using `[0]` for pointer dereference and no handle typedefs and are we in C and... urgh. I'm out.

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to change the value of m2 (according to the value of m1) without changing the value of m1

Comment: Okay, first of all, "doesn't work" will not give you any answers because we don't know WHAT doesn't work. We could try eunning your program, but tbh, if your code was only a little bit less ugly, inconsistent and misleading, I would have thought about it.

Comment: My code is so ugly because I semplified (I know that is stupid allocating memory for a variable 1x1! In the real code it's a matrix). The part of code that doesn't work is after \\ (and I know that is totally incorrect, but i don't know how to fix it).

Comment: Yes, now it works! It's a month that I'm working on this project and I'm exhausted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `A renew()` to `void renew()` and the code works.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
private:

int **m1;
int **m2;

void allocate_mem(int ***ptr){
    *ptr = new int*[1];
    (*ptr)[0] = new int[1];
}

public:

A(){
    allocate_mem(&m1);
    m1[0][0] = 1;
    allocate_mem(&m2);
    m2[0][0] = 1;
}

//I need a method that change m2 (according to the value of m1) without changhig the value of m1
void renew(){
    if(m1[0][0]>0)
        m2[0][0] = 1000;
}

~A(){
    delete[] m1[0];
    delete[] m1;
    delete[] m2[0];
    delete[] m2;
}

void create_output(){
    cout << m1[0][0] << endl << m2[0][0] << endl;
}

};

int main(){
  A mat;
  mat.create_output();
  mat.renew();
  mat.create_output();

  return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
 1
 1
 1
 1000
```